# My while loop won't echo out data from my database

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

Right, so I'm trying to execute a news function, and I've coded it the same way I always do, but some some reason it won't work as the data is not showing, although my mysql_num_rows function is detecting the data in the database.

require('php/connect.php');

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows=!0)
    {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
        {

        $body = $row['body'];
        $date = $row['date'];

        echo "Posted on: "strtotime($date)" |";
        echo "<hr width='20%' align='left'";
        echo "$body <br /> <hr width='100%' />";

        }

    }
    else    
        die("There are no news posts to show.")
```

If anyone could tell me what is going wrong in my code, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You have a strange way of writing the inequality - does `=!` actually work? Also, I normally concat strings using `"."`, is `"Posted on: "strtotime($date)" |"` valid?

Comment: Yeah it works, it's not the $numrows that's a problem though, it's just not receiving the information form that database, although it is connecting. And the =!0 is just a different way of saying "If it doesn't equal 0"

Comment: I guess you mean $numrows!=0, not =!. Even though the first is a mistake, it always evaluates to 1. Which is not the problem in this case, it's probably not what you intend, and will make some wonder when reviewing the code.

Comment: `=!` works: it assigns the result of the application of logical operator ! to 0, which is 1 to $numrows.

Comment: Ahh I see, my apologies, but even with all of the error reporting so far, and using $numrows!=0, the problem still occurs, it's still returning a value of 1, which is the amount of rows in my database, although it's not parsing the data into the $date & $body variables, so they are just remaining blank :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this `if($numrows)`  instead of `if($numrows=!0)`

AND use

```
echo "Posted on: ".strtotime($date)." |";
```

instead of using

`echo "Posted on: "strtotime($date)" |";`

Ad there is one more mistakes in

```
echo "<hr width='20%' align='left' />";   // closing tag for <hr>
echo "$body <br /> <hr width='100%' />";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it

```
if($numrows=!0)
```

To

```
if($numrows != 0)
```

Comment: @aiden: look at @gaurav 's answer you also have problem with concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Not about your problem, but `if($numrows=!0)` will be ALWAYS true.
Use `if($numrows!=0)`

Answer (score 0):

One thing is for sure, it's the $numrows thing you added to the query. That or there is nothing to echo out. Try the query without checking if it returned anything or not.

Comment: I did, but I still had the same problem with the variables, it's like they are not pulling the information from the table.